# Connect to same database in two different Gitlab CI

Tags: laravel, continuous-integration, gitlab, cd

I have configured two Gitlab CI and both of them are for laravel apps.

the first one ( my first app ) has a lot of migration in it and therefore in CI pipelines it migrates into the database.

and my second app is just to run tests for the first one.

Now, my question is when I want to run my second app's Gitlab CI, it occurs error which is true because all of my migrations are in the first app and therefore my second app hasn't any database and tables to run tests on them.

what's your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is about getting errors for failing at run migration Update your migration and append checking like below before creating tables and columns:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
    //
}

if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'email')) {
    //
}
```

Comment: thanks, could you please read my question again and update your answer in true way? I asked something else

Comment: @TomasShelby you mean that you want exactly run the migration in both apps? I think you need two environments with a separated database